# If stimulus triggers dopamine release, can dopamine release trigger memory recall of stimulus?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, sleep, dreams, dopamine

[Modern science of sleep is starting to lean towards a viewpoint that dopamine has an important function in dreaming](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0149763412000899), and that dopaminergic pathways - mesolimbic and mesocortical are activated during dreaming.

Here's what the list of functions that [dopamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine#In_the_brain) is responsible for in the human brain:

> Inside the brain, dopamine plays important roles in motor control,
>   motivation, arousal, cognition, and reward, as well as a number of
>   basic lower-level functions including lactation, sexual gratification,
>   and nausea.

With this in mind, I'm posing the following question: **Can random activation of dopaminergic system during dreaming cause dreams of stimuli which activated dopaminergic system during waking state?** In other words, if perceiving sexual stimuli triggers dopaminergic system activation, can similar activation during dreaming cause recollection of the sexual stimuli?

To simplify:

- Seeing erotic image -> causes dopaminergic system activation
- Activation of dopaminergic system -> can it cause recall of erotic image or some other experience from the list above?

Has there been any research into what happens when a person's dopaminergic system (mesolimbic and mesocortical pathways of Ventral Tegmental Area) is artificially stimulated (like during brain surgery) - does this cause recall of experiences, desires or cravings or other things people "want"?

Comment: How does one even activate the dopaminergic system non-invasively?

Comment: Apparently it gets activated as a part of the dreaming process

Comment: I meant in terms of a non-invasive experimental procedure as a method to separate correlation from causation.

Comment: I originally meant invasive procedures, like brain surgery - from what I understand surgeons probe brain regions to make sure they are cutting the correct thing. Maybe at some point some surgeon poked parts of dopaminergic system and noticed the results. I also read of rats with artificially implanted electrodes stimulating those areas, but rats would not be able to relay subjective experience of those activations.

Comment: I don't know much about how the brain works and I would rather not learn expert results about it because I may have the theoretical ability to sense them myself and would rather not get told them before I sense them on my own, ruining my ability to sense them for myself. I do realize a brain cannot have awareness of as much information as every single detail about itself which might be around 10^14 bits of information. I'm wondering if the reason why you asked about dopamine is because dopamine is involved in part of the process of a neuron firing and a neuron cannot fire at all in the absense

Comment: of surrounding dopamine.